# make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: linux, makefile, gnome-3

I got this while installing gnome-calender on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
home@JP-PC:~/Documents/gnome-calendar-3.22.1$ ./configure
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles...     yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for intltool >= 0.40.6... 0.50.2 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.18.2
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.22... yes
checking for _NL_TIME_FIRST_WEEKDAY... checking for style of include used              by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
yes
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to i686-pc-linux-gnu         format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain          format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries...       yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for floor... no
checking for memset... yes
checking for nl_langinfo... yes
checking for pow... no
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking for glib-mkenums... /usr/bin/glib-mkenums
checking whether C compiler accepts -Werror=unknown-warning-option... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -fno-strict-aliasing... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wall... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wextra... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wundef... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wnested-externs... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wwrite-strings... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wpointer-arith... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wmissing-declarations... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wmissing-prototypes... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wstrict-prototypes... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wredundant-decls... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wno-unused-parameter... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wno-missing-field-initializers... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wdeclaration-after-statement... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wformat=2... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wold-style-definition... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wcast-align... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wformat-nonliteral... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wformat-security... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wsign-compare... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wstrict-aliasing... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wshadow... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Winline... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wpacked... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wmissing-format-attribute... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wmissing-noreturn... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Winit-self... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wredundant-decls... (cached) yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wmissing-include-dirs... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wunused-but-set-variable... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Warray-bounds... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wimplicit-function-declaration... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wreturn-type... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wswitch-enum... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wswitch-default... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-parameter... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wno-error=missing-field-    initializers... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Werror=unknown-warning-option...     (cached) no
checking whether the linker accepts -Wl,--no-as-needed... yes
checking for CALENDAR... no
configure: error: Package requirements (
              gmodule-export-2.0
              gio-2.0 >= 2.43.4
              glib-2.0 >= 2.43.4
              goa-1.0 >= 3.2.0
              gtk+-3.0 >= 3.21.6
              libecal-1.2 >= 3.13.90
              libedataserver-1.2 >= 3.17.1
              libedataserverui-1.2 >= 3.17.1
              libical >= 1.0
              gsettings-desktop-schemas >= 3.21.2) were not met:

Requested 'gio-2.0 >= 2.43.4' but version of GIO is 2.40.2
Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.43.4' but version of GLib is 2.40.2
No package 'goa-1.0' found
Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.21.6' but version of GTK+ is 3.10.8
No package 'libecal-1.2' found
No package 'libedataserver-1.2' found
No package 'libedataserverui-1.2' found
No package 'libical' found
No package 'gsettings-desktop-schemas' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CALENDAR_CFLAGS
and CALENDAR_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Now after "./configure" running make command shows

"make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

```
home@JP-PC:~/Documents/gnome-calendar-3.22.1$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
home@JP-PC:~/Documents/gnome-calendar-3.22.1$
```

I read on some other thread to first run "make clean" then "./configure".
But "make clean" show this error.

```
home@JP-PC:~/Documents/gnome-calendar-3.22.1$ make clean
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
```

So can anyone help me to solve this.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you have a configure error, you need to fulfil the dependencies. as stated at the end of ./configure output

Comment: Yes but there are too many of them. I think I should read the gnome-calender installation documentation first which mentions to use jhbuild. Thanks